# Embed facebook posts?

Tags: facebook, embed

How can I embed just the posts made on a Facebook page into another website? Ive read a few things about this but all they talk about embedding more than just the posts made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has a blog post with a section titled [Graph API to pull comments](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490/) that would allow you to render all the comments on page.  They have sample code in PHP, but you would just need to make an http request with whatever language you are using to https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids={YOUR_URL}